# How to use sequelize beforeCreate to autogenerate Id value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am tryiong to generate a `BINARY(16)` value for a model that Id.

I used the defaultValue parameter but ended up getting

> duplicate key errors in mysql

.

So i found If I use beforeCreate then it would be uniqe every time but when Im doing the actual create im getting

> Id can not be null errors

my model:

```
const utility = require('utils/utilities');


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const weddings = sequelize.define(
        'weddings', {
            Id: {
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                type: 'BINARY(16)',
            },
            Name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
            HouseId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
                references: {
                    model: 'house',
                    key: 'Id',
                },
            },
            WDate: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
            Active: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
        },

        {
            hooks: {
                beforeCreate() {
                const generateValue = Buffer.from(utility.generateUID().replace('-', ''), 'hex');
                weddings.Id = generateValue;
                }
            }
        }, {
            tableName: 'weddings',
        }
    );

    return weddings;
};
```

error:

> weddings.Id cannot be null

What am I missing?

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can just simply skip the id field definition to let sequelize handle it.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: If you don't initialize Id by yourself, sequelize will handle it for you. It will create a field named id. Which is primary key and auto increment is active. However it won't be a binary(16). But if the main reason is just having a primary key it should do the work. I always use that approach. No problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instance hook like this:

```
const utility = require('utils/utilities');


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const weddings = sequelize.define(
        'weddings', {
            Id: {
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                type: 'BINARY(16)',
            },
            Name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
            HouseId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
                references: {
                    model: 'house',
                    key: 'Id',
                },
            },
            WDate: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
            Active: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                comment: 'null',
            },
        },

        {
        }, {
            tableName: 'weddings',
        }
    );

    weddings.beforeCreate(async (data, options) => {
        data.Id = await Buffer.from(utility.generateUID().replace('-', ''), 'hex');

    });

    return weddings;
};
```

If you want to emit hooks for each individual record, along with the bulk hooks you can pass `individualHooks: true` to the call.

```
table.update( req.body, {
  where: where,
  returning: true,
  individualHooks: true
  plain: true
})
```

create:

```
  db.weddings.create({
      ...args,
    }),
```

for other information you can read it at:
https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/hooks.html